# What is the use of Secure Protocol Data Management (SPDM)?

Tags: authentication, cryptographic-hardware

By going through the document: https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0274_1.2.0.pdf
I could get that this spec will be used to verify the identify and attestation of h/w & firmware with the help of TCG_UDS spec. I want to know that do we have any other advantage of having SPDM specification?